# Why no cmd_vel topic during ROS + Gazebo Turtlebot Simulation?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been having a very difficult time trying to understand why my system does not have the cmd_vel topic. I am trying to get a ROS system running with Gazebo so that I can work through tutorials and learn ROS. I started with the ROS Development Studio (online) and it was great! But sooner or later one must be able to get ROS going on a local system. So I built a Ubuntu system and installed ROS + Gazebo, then installed Turtlebot including the simulator. It all works! I can launch a Turtlebot simulation then launch the Turtlebot_teleop package and I am able to move the robot around.
But when I list the running topics cmd_vel is not one of them. These are the list of topics grep'd on "cmd":

```
scott@Ubvm:~/catkin_ws/devel$ rostopic list | grep cmd
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/switch
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
```

No /cmd_vel ! So I can't work through tutorials to drive the robot around. Besides, I just don't understand why it is not there but teleop works.

Could someone tell me why I do not see the cmd_vel topic?

System info:

Ubuntu 16.04

ROS Kinetic

Gazebo 7 (not sure exactly which version but it launches and runs)

Installed Turtlebot based on Indigo install but replaced with kinetic.

```
sudo apt-get install 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-apps 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactions 
ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator 
ros-kinetic-kobuki-ftdi 
ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon 
ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library 
ros-kinetic-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312416/why-no-cmd_vel-topic-during-ros-+-gazebo-turtlebot-simulation?/) by [scottr](https://answers.ros.org/users/39401/scottr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pranali](https://answers.ros.org/users/68158/pranali/) on 2021-01-18**:
I had the same issue and found a video - https://youtu.be/2WBDRbYmE7A

This video made sense.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the `/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi` topic. If you do

```
rostopic info /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
```

you should see that its message type is of a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message. If you look at [this file (line 40)](https://github.com/markwsilliman/turtlebot/blob/master/goforward.py#L40) from the [Going Forward and Avoiding Obstacles with Code tutorial](https://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/13/) from the [turtlebot tutorials](https://learn.turtlebot.com/), you'll see that the `/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi` topic is used.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-10**:
A [mux](https://wiki.ros.org/yocs_cmd_vel_mux) is being used here which is why you're not seeing a `/cmd_vel` topic exactly.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-10**:
Note that using the `/cmd_vel` topic to carry commands is a ROS *convention* and is not enforced which is another reason why you may find other topics being used to carry commands.

**Comment by [scottr](https://answers.ros.org/users/39401/scottr/) on 2019-01-25**:
The revelation that cmd_vel is only a convention helped immensely.  The strange thing on my system is that writing to cmd_vel_mux/input/navi does nothing.  I have to write to cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop to make the robot go.  That topic is there whether the teleop node is running or not.

**Comment by [scottr](https://answers.ros.org/users/39401/scottr/) on 2019-01-25**:
Maybe it is because it is only a Gazebo simulation.  I’m just happy to be able to control the robot and move on. :)